# Pie chart in ggplot2 and percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a pie chart with percentages. In order to do that I wrote this lines of codes

```
library(ggplot2)
      df <- data.frame(
        group = c("Male", "Female"),
        value = c(15000, 10000))
      head(df)

      p <- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y = value, fill=group)) +
        geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + coord_polar("y", start=0)
      require(scales)
      p + scale_fill_brewer("Blues") + blank_theme +
        geom_text(aes(y = value/2 + c(0, cumsum(value)[-length(value)]),
                      label = percent(value/100)), size=5)
```

But unfortunately these lines of code don’t give me percentage numbers. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and  get real percentages of  60% for male and 40% for female.

[image]

Comment: Try with `label = scales::percent(value/sum(value))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just `sum` to count both genders. Example: `percent(1000 / sum(df$value))` will return `"4%"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'scales'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     discard
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     col_factor

df <- data.frame(
  group = c("Male", "Female"),
  value = c(15000, 10000)
)
df
#>    group value
#> 1   Male 15000
#> 2 Female 10000

ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  scale_fill_brewer("Blues") +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(
    y = value / 2 + c(0, cumsum(value)[-length(value)]),
    label = percent(value / sum(value))
  ), size = 5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>